# Who actually is Dajjal?

Tags: history, dajjal

Salaam brothers and sisters. I was just watching a video on youtube about Dajjal that how he would look like and the signs which will be shown before he arrives. We all know that. But, what I want to know is that WHO ACTUALLY IS DAJJAL? Where did he come from? What's his history? Who was he born to? I want to know about the life of Dajjal. I did intense googling but, with no luck.

Any authentic references will be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I asked the same question a few months ago. You probably won't find any answers here, the matter concerning Dajjal's origins is quite possibly not known (I am not sure of it since I asked the same thing myself). I am currently reading [all the Hadith related to Dajjal](https://sunnah.com/search/?q=Dajjal) to figure this guy's deal out myself. You might as well do the same. That said, nowhere on the internet could I find Dajjal's origins, who's this person, how he became Iblees' fav dude, how he obtain superpowers, why he locked up, is he human if he is then how is Allah testing him and stuff.